# Ubuntu 22.04, problem with GPU NVIDIA A2, Wayland and VGA

Tags: 22.04, cuda, wayland, nouveau, vga

My PC has an integrated video card with 3 outoput ports (HDMI, DP and VGA) and an additional NVIDIA A2 video card dedicated to CUDA functions. This video card has no video outputs since it is for computational use only.

At the time I use Nouveau drivers, Wayland works properly with all 3 video outputs.
However, when I install the Nvidia video card drivers, the system starts directly in X11 and does not allow me to switch to Wayland. On X11 I do not have the option to run VGA.

My need is to have CUDA functionality available and, at the same time, that all three monitors (VGA, HDMI, DP) are running.
Is there any way to install NVIDIA video card drivers without them affecting the graphics environment?

I thank you in advance for your help